# Can't access localhost on MacBook from iPhone Safari, shows loading bar then fails?

Tags: iphone, macos, localhost

I have a nodejs server running on port 3000 and I'm trying to access that from my iPhone.

I have tried:

1. The Macs IP Address (found in "network")
2. The Macs "name" (computer-name.local:3000)
3. Changing the WLAN
4. Opening "Internet Sharing" in "Sharing" unter System preferences
5. Accessing the site through chrome
6. Tested another iPhone than mine, same result as you can see on the picture
7. Tested an XAMPP Server on port 80, same result as you can see on the picture
8. Checked firewall (it's deactivated)

[image: This is what happens]

You can see on the image that there is indeed a loading bar, it doesn't directly show "site not found" or anything. So what I am guessing is that I have to configure something more on my MacBook, but I can't find out what. I tried everything written in other posts about this. The final message I get(after like 20 seconds) is "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding".

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked firewall settings? Perhaps you need to open the port or the server application in System & Preferences -> Security and privacy -> Firewall -> Firewall Options.

Comment: Ah sorry my firewall is deactivated, I'll add that

Comment: If it's disabled your computer should accept any network requests… Weird. Perhaps you have any kind of network isolation and your router doesn't allow requests between peers on the same network?

Comment: I thought so as well, we then tried to setup a personal hotspot and connected the macbook and the iphone to it, still didn't work. Unless the personal hotspot restricts this, it should be another cause..

Comment: Perhaps Node.JS is enabled only to accept request from localhost? Never used it but I remember in Apache it has to be enabled, it wasn't default setup.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem. I am facing the same issue. @ManuMateos